# calculate an avg with no decimals

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish I could figure this out. I need to produce a table with an average called AVG_AMT (integer) and has no decimals. It can either round or truncate. It really does not matter for this table.

This what I have tried to write:

```
SELECT `TC Code`, AVG(ALW_AMT) as int(8,0) AS AVG_AMT
FROM OFFICE_Claims_Physicians
GROUP BY `TC Code`
ORDER BY `TC Code`;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    `TC Code`, 
    round(AVG(ALW_AMT),0) AS AVG_AMT
FROM 
    OFFICE_Claims_Physicians
GROUP BY 
    `TC Code`
ORDER BY 
    `TC Code`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [ROUND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function

```
SELECT `TC Code`, ROUND(AVG(ALW_AMT)) as int(8,0) AS AVG_AMT
FROM OFFICE_Claims_Physicians
GROUP BY `TC Code`
ORDER BY `TC Code`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Round function

```
SELECT `TC Code`, ROUND(AVG(ALW_AMT)) as int(8,0) AS AVG_AMT
FROM OFFICE_Claims_Physicians
GROUP BY `TC Code`
ORDER BY `TC Code`;
```

If you want the decimal for only one or two place

```
 SELECT `TC Code`, ROUND(AVG(ALW_AMT),1/2) as int(8,0) AS AVG_AMT
 FROM OFFICE_Claims_Physicians
 GROUP BY `TC Code`
 ORDER BY `TC Code`;
```